# Are plantains sattvic?

Tags: puranas, iskcon, prasad, sattvik, diet

According to Hari Bhakti Vilasa 8.158

「 What Is Inedible (For the Purpose of Offering to the Lord)

In the Kurma Purana it is said:

"One should avoid eggplant, plantain, safflower, ashmantaka, onion, garlic, sour cereal, and the sap of trees." 」

The word used for "plantain" is "jalikasakam"/"jalikashakam".

My question is, why is there a restriction on plantain?

And secondly, perhaps much more importantly, why is plantain often offered as naivedya/prasada despite these restrictions?

Comment: I have never seen a plantain restriction in practice, or in any other scripture. Eggplant, onion, garlic, surely is not accepted in Vaiṣṇava tradition, but never heard of plantain restriction.